# Using bash echo command to input into a python one liner

Tags: python, bash, echo, stdin

I am trying to input a string using echo into a Python one liner then perform a Caeasar's Cipher on the string.

One of the examples my instructor gave me was this.

```
~ $ echo "Hello Holly." | python -c "import sys; [print(line) for line in sys.stdin]"
```

The output is suppose to be: `Hello Holly.`

How ever when I type the command in I get:

```
File "<string>", line 1
 import sys; [print(line) for line in sys.stdin]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point out the error to me. I am using Python 2.6 on Centos 6.

Thanks.

Comment: Using list comprehensions simply to apply a function to each item in a list without caring about the resulting list is a bad habit to get into; shame on your instructor. Use `... | python -c 'import sys; print "".join(sys.stdin)'` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2 `print` is a statement, not a function. Try this instead:

```
echo "Hello Holly." | python -c "import sys; print [line for line in sys.stdin]"
```

Alternatively, you could use the following to just print plain text (thanks @mgilson):

```
echo "Hello Holly." | python -c "import sys; print ' '.join([line for line in sys.stdin])"
```

Comment: Just to elaborate, using Python 3, OP's implementation will work :)

Comment: Looks OK now, but you're printing a `list`, not plain text as OP wants.  The cleanest is to probably `' '.join` it or something...

Comment: @JustinC -- That's not always the case... it depends on how you compile, etc.

Comment: bob@pbx:~ $ echo "Hello Holly." | python -c " import sys; print [line for line in sys.stdin]"
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; print [line for line in sys.stdin] 
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @user3375720 make sure you copy and paste directly. It works fine for me using Python 2.6 on CentOS 6. It looks like you have a space between the `"` following `python -c` and `import` - that's probably what's causing the IndentationError.

Comment: bob@pbx:~ $  echo "Hello Holly." | python -c "import sys; print [line for line in sys.stdin]"
['Hello Holly.\n']
bob@pbx:~ $  echo -n "Hello Holly." | python -c "import sys; print [line for line in sys.stdin]"
['Hello Holly.']

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to get rid of the brackets

Comment: @user3375720 - use the second line to get rid of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using python2 while your isntructor is using python 3.